# Applying filter option from an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to apply filter option from an array.

```
options = [
    "car",
    "bike",
]
```

I have multiple filter select, that's why using an array to contain more then one option.

and let's say there is array that I want to filter.

```
array = [
   "car",
   "fruit",
   "keyboard",
   "computer"
]
```

if the option is string like `options = "car"` then the thing is very easy

```
if (!options.length) {
    return array;
} else {
    return array.filter(item => {                    
        return item === options;
    })
}
```

But the thing is how can I handle if the `options` is not `string` but an array?

For example I tried to put filter function inside for loop.

```
let len = options.length
console.log(len)
for (let i = 0; i < len; index++) {
    return array.filter(item => {                    
        return item === array[i];
    })
}
```

but it didn't worked out. It's only taking first selected from an array.

Comment: What's your desired output for the array situation? `['car']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
return options.includes(item);
```

Comment: This little touch/guide helped a lot. thank you, solved it. I will accept it as answer...